# Why asp net api does not run from docker regisry?

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have the following problem: I wrote an api on asp net, then I created a docker image for it via cmd. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApi/WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

When running locally, everything works fine, the application runs in the container and responds to requests, but when I try to push the image to the local registry and then create the container from there, I get a container created with this error:

> The command could not be loaded, possibly because:   * You intended to
> execute a .NET application:
> The application 'WebApi.dll' does not exist.   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
> No .NET SDKs were found. Download a .NET SDK: https://aka.ms/dotnet/download Learn about SDK resolution:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

The commands I used for push:

```
docker tag user-service:1.0 <ip>:<port>/user-service:1.0`

docker push <ip>:<port>/user-service:1.0
```